# Can you take a iPhone 5c sim card and put it in another iPhone 5c?

Tags: iphone, sim

Can an iPhone 5c SIM card be moved to another iPhone 5c?

Comment: Yes you can move a sim to a different phone

Answer (score 5):

Providing the iPhone 5c that you are moving the SIM card to is not locked to a different network, this is possible.